# Elastic Beanstalk logs security credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for our Java/Tomcat application. How can we prevent that multiple secure credentials are printed in the log file in plain text? We have several environment variables, which shouldn't be in log files and the database password (RDS) is automatically in the log file. Is it possible to obfuscate the passwords automatically?

E.g.:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DRDS_PASSWORD=XXXXX
```

Comment: Try changing the logging to a higher level, if that's an option.

Comment: Changing the logging level is not possible with the log configuration in the application. These are log entries from the Tomcat itself. I don't know how to change the logging level for Tomcat in Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Beanstalk has a GUI for setting ENV variables, can you use that instead of passing them as command line arguments?